Is convex cone of inner products finitely generated?
Let's consider the set of inner products on $\mathbf R^n$ (any real vector space of finite dimension). It is a convex cone (in the space of bylinear forms). By that I mean that any linear combination of inner products with strictly positive coefficients is also an inner product. Now I'm interested if this cone is finitely generated.
It's clear that convex cone in finitely-dimensional space has no reason to be finitely generated (for example regular cone $\{(x,y,z):z\ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}\subset\mathbf R^3$ is not). So how can I check if it is finitely generated?

Your your question is not about the cone of all inner product, but only those whose matrix expression has positive coefficients?

This cone is in "bilinear" bijection with $\mathcal{S}_n^{++} (\mathbb{R})$ the symmetric definite positive matrices
